Send code to teams group through webhooks
I want to send a custom message to teams that is going is looking like the image attached.
I am doing it by this code in python. But I would the code part of my message to be formatted in sql and have the copy code button like the other image. I havent found any reference on how I should send this information. properly I have found regarding how to send the code.
    html_table = spark.sql(query+ " LIMIT 10").toPandas().to_html(index=False,justify='center',float_format="{:,.2f}".format).replace('<td>','<td style="text-align: center;">')

if num_outliers > 10:
  n = 10
else:
  n = num_outliers

html_message = f"""<strong>{CONS_CATALOG.upper()}.{CONS_SCHEMA_BUILD.upper()}.{CONS_TABLE_CONVIVA_HISTORICAL_COST.upper()}</strong><br>
<hr>
A total of {num_outliers} outliers has been detected on {date} for <em><a href="{CONS_TABLE_URL}">{CONS_CATALOG}.{CONS_SCHEMA_BUILD}.{CONS_TABLE_CONVIVA_HISTORICAL_COST}</a></em><br>
<br>The TOP {n} outliers are: <br> <br>
{html_table}
<br> To see the outliers run the following script on <em><a href="{CONS_TABLE_URL}">{CONS_CATALOG}.{CONS_SCHEMA_BUILD}.{CONS_TABLE_CONVIVA_HISTORICAL_COST}</a></em>: <br>
<pre>{query}
</pre>
payload ={"text":html_message,
        'parse_mode': 'HTML'
         }


# Set the headers for the request
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}


# Make the POST request
response = requests.post(CONS_TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

# Print the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Alert created successfully:", response.json())
else:
    print("Failed to create alert:", response.status_code, response.text)




Currently this scenario is not supported. You will get copy button option via UI only not through webhook message formatting. To better achieve your requirements, we recommend submitting this feature request through the Teams Feedback Portal. This is the best way to ensure your idea is considered for future updates.
We appreciate your input and encourage you to share any additional thoughts!
